# FastAPI SQLAlchemy cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to return list of operations and getting error

```
@router.get("/")
async def get_specific_operations(operation_type: str, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    query = select(operation).where(operation.c.type == operation_type)
    result = await session.execute(query)
    return result.all()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: [TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Comment: Python version 3.8

Comment: The `all()` method in SQLAlchemy returns a `Sequence` object with `Row` values - FastAPIs default JSON encoder has no idea what do with that type of object. Define a pydantic response model with config set to `orm_mode=True` or return a list of dictionaries instead.

Answer (score 2):

try instead of `result.all()` to do this `result.scalars().all()`

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `result.all()` with `result.mappings().all()`
It worked in my code.

Comment: With `sqlalchemy2` + `sqlmodel` this seems to be the right approach!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit of details to @matslindh's answer:

1. in your `schemas.py` define your response model adding `model_config`

```
class Operation(BaseModel):
  model_config: ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

  prop1: type1
  prop2: type2
  ...
```

`ConfigDict` is imported from `pydantic` as well

2. Set your response model to `List[Operation]`

```
from typing import List
from schemas import Operation
...
@router.get("/", response_model=List[Operation])
```

In this case  `response.all()` will be processed by `pydantic` and converted to serialized response